# losing data betwen classes

Tags: java, android

i have basic downloader class
where i download and decode bitmap as well.
but if i try to decode out of this class, i get my bitmap = null.

```
public void add_item(String _txt, String _url) {
    try {
        Downloader dw = new Downloader(_url, context);
        InputStream s = dw.execute().get();
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(s); // <<<<<< bitmap is null
        bmp.add(b);
    }  catch (ExecutionException e) { Toast.makeText(this.context, "Ошибка загрузки картинки", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
       catch (InterruptedException e) { Toast.makeText(this.context, "Ошибка загрузки картинки", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
}
```

downloader.java

```
package com.example.john.weather;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Downloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, InputStream> {

String url;
Context mContext;

public Downloader(String _url, Context _context){
    this.url = _url;
    this.mContext = _context;
}

@Override
protected InputStream doInBackground(Void... params) {
    InputStream s;
    try{
        s = download(this.url);
        //Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(s); // <<<<<< Bitmap is good
        return s;
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Ошибка загрузки "+url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null; }
    catch (IOException e){
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Ошибка загрузки "+url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }
}

private InputStream download(String url) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

    return input;
}

}
```

i have basic downloader class
where i download and decode bitmap as well.
but if i try to decode out of this class, i get my bitmap = null.

Comment: how do you decode out of that class?

Comment: Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(s);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes just find the solution.
InputStream is moved into byte[] and then returned.
So decode can be done

```
byte[] data = dw.execute().get();
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
```

downloader.java

```
package com.example.john.weather;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Downloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, byte[]> {

String url;
Context mContext;

public Downloader(String _url, Context _context){
    this.url = _url;
    this.mContext = _context;
}

@Override
protected byte[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
    InputStream s;
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try{
        s = download(this.url);

        /*s.available() can be used only for small downloaded files
        Returns an estimated number of bytes that can be read or skipped without blocking for more input.
        Note that this method provides such a weak guarantee that it is not very useful in practice....*/
        byte[] data = new byte[s.available()];
        int n;
        while ((n = s.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            buffer.write(data, 0, n);
        }
        buffer.flush();

        return buffer.toByteArray();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Ошибка загрузки "+url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null; }
    catch (IOException e){
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Ошибка загрузки "+url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(byte[] result) {

}

private InputStream download(String url) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

    return input;
}

}
```

UPD. More stable convertation to byte[]

```
@Override
protected byte[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
    InputStream input;
    try{
        input = download(this.url);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) { Toast.makeText(mContext, "Ошибка загрузки "+url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); return null; }
    catch (IOException e){ Toast.makeText(mContext, "Ошибка загрузки "+url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); return null; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the problem is within the `Downloader` class in `download()` method. You need to load the content of the stream before moving the execution to another thread (which is the main thread in this case)

Comment: command dw.execute() will give result you told. But command dw.execute().get() wait until thread completely be done.

Comment: can you try to decode the bitmap on postExecute() ?

Comment: just tried, result is NULL.      @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream result) {
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(result);
        b.getWidth();
    }

Comment: you need to load the content of the stream in the background thread